# Removing the margin from bottom in android Relativelayout

Tags: android

Hello i have used a Relativelayout in android using XML but when i see image in graphical layout there is small margin left at bottom in different screensizes.How to remove that margin.I also used a ScrollView in layout.

Comment: It would be nice with a screenshot and some source code to see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set bottom margin in negative

like

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="-10dip"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have used padding for your layout,

Better post your layout file and/or screenshot.